# How to do advance "listing" for android views

Tags: android, user-interface

I've been searching for a while now how to do some "Advance" lists like the facebook news feed and I don't think I am using the right keywords to search how to do that. I'm still quite new to android environment.

This is what I am trying to achieve:
[image: Example1]
[image: Example2]

How would I achieve a kind of list like that? Can I just do somekind of layout with a scrollbar and feed in some custom views? Do I need to do some kind of advance list?

Thank you for refering me to some useful information

Comment: In particular Facebook has an article on their blog related to how they implemented the list on android https://code.facebook.com/posts/879498888759525/fast-rendering-news-feed-on-android/

Comment: That's quite advanced for me, but it will help my orientate my search, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity's sake, I would recommend maybe you should use a `ScrollView` nesting a Vertical `LinearLayout` and dynamically add all your child items in there.

I know...it's not the *right* way, but this is coming from a (somewhat) beginner's point of view here myself. (I've been coding all my life, but I was immediately not a fan of Lists and "Adapters" when I got into Android.)

So, if/when you need to search through/categorize/sort/manage your items I would suggest maybe using `View.setTag()` to store key information about each child, and either a) loop through all your child elements for deep searching, or b) use `View.findViewsWithText()` or `findViewWithTag()` for quick searching/categorizing.

It can get dirty pretty quick if you have to do extensive sorting, but in my head (and maybe yours) I would rather use what I know rather than learn what I don't know.

I didn't intend this to be an rock-solid answer, but it's a lot of info to cover in the comments.

Happy programming